# Remove the messages of the code output in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

In the jupyter notebook I use with R kernel, I can get procedure hints as following:

```
pausing 1 second between requests for more than 5 symbols
```

showing as [image]

My question is what if I want to hide the messages below the cell?

As you can see, I have tried `options(warn=-1)`, but it could not work. The entire code cell is :

```
etf_weekly_returns <- function(ticker) {

symbols <- getSymbols(ticker, auto.assign = TRUE, warnings = FALSE)

etf_prices <- do.call(merge, lapply(symbols, function(x) Cl(get(x))))

etf_returns <- do.call(merge, lapply(etf_prices, 
                                     function(x) periodReturn(x, period = 'weekly', type = 'log')))

#Change the column names to the sector names from our dataframe above.

colnames(etf_returns) <- etf_ticker_sector$sector

etf_returns

}
etf_returns <- etf_weekly_returns(etf_ticker_sector$ticker)
options(warn=-1)
```

Comment: I don't think those are `warnings` at least as R defines that term. You should probably be looking for advice about "messages". The `?message` page says`The default handler sends the message to the stderr() connection.`  And the `?stderr` page says `The stdout() and stderr() connections can be re-directed by sink...`. However, The ?sink page warns: `Do not sink the messages stream unless you understand the source code implementing it and hence the pitfalls.`

Comment: `suppressMessages()` maybe?

Comment: I have thought of what @42 have mentioned as well, so a more efficient way  is that the message shows on the running jupyter notebook, but not on the re-opened notebook saved for sharing with others. I know in magic key words for IPython, there are some messages removing way. I doubt if it exists any in R kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried suppressWarnings()?

[image]

Comment: Yeah I have tried and it did not work, but as what @42 mentioned, it seems not a warning, but a general message for "hints" .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to use the `suppressMessages()` function, in this case. Jupyter notebooks generally classify both messages and warnings as stderr (which is output in red), so you just need to determine whether the functions that you're using are outputting messages or warnings. Once you identify that, you can suppress with the appropriate suppression call.